# Multiple Replace issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, sql-server-2008-r2

I made a Bulk Import from a File.txt. One of the columns has, after Import, the following text:

```
30 x 1,5 mm, O-Ring, EPDM, 70░▒5░ Shore A, schwarz, Tol. nach ISO 3601
```

But it has to be:

```
30 x 1,5 mm, O-Ring, EPDM, 70°±5° Shore A, schwarz, Tol. nach ISO 3601
```

I want to use a multiple replace, like this:

```
,ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([ARTTXT], '░', '°'), '▒', '±'), '▀', 'ß'), '') AS [ARTTXT]
```

But then I get:

```
30 x 1,5 mm, O-Ring, EPDM, 70°°5° Shore A, schwarz, Tol. nach ISO 3601
```

And another row:

```
Spritzschutz-Ring SRP, Typ SS, DN 25, PP, rot, PN 10-40 f³r Flanschverb. aus 2 Vorschweißfl. EN 1092-1 Fom B,
```

So you see the `°` and the `ß` work, but the `±` doesn't.

Why? I'm using  a SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thank you.

Greetz Vegeta_77

Update:
@Damien_The_Unbeliever
Use NVARCHAR is much better. It works! But finaly I have the problem:

...mittelgr³n --> should be mittelgrün
So my replace is:

```
REPLACE([ARTTXT], N'³', N'ü')
```

So mittelgrün works. But also I'm replacing:
2-381 -->  2-ü81

Why? The replace is not ... , N'3', 'ü'

Comment: THX jarlh. But it have to be: Vorschweißfl. --> at "And another row:" Because the ß works!

Comment: Sounds like maybe a collation issue.

Comment: Now I tried # instead of ± --> but it's 70°°5°

Comment: And also I tried to change the order of the replace statements --> no effect...

Comment: It looks like you have a collation that doesn't distinguish between the two different characters between `70` and `5`.   It's treating them both the same.

Comment: Are you able to shift everything over to using `nvarchar` rather than `varchar`? `declare @t nvarchar(max) 
set @t = N'30 x 1,5 mm, O-Ring, EPDM, 70░▒5░ Shore A, schwarz, Tol. nach ISO 3601'

select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@t, N'░', N'°'), N'▒', N'±'), N'▀', N'ß')` prints the expected output.

Comment: I strongly suggest not to use the copied chars (░▒ and so on) but their ascii/unicode numbers. Take the string and check the ascii code at the corresponding positions. Afterwards you can write a REPLACE(@t, char(@asciicode), 'ü (or corresponding ascii code'). Using the copied text can have funny side effects: they differ from editor to editor and with this might lead to varying results. Here some examples:

    SELECT unicode(N'¦');
    SELECT unicode(N'¦');
    
    SELECT nchar(9617);
    SELECT nchar(9618);

Comment: SELECT unicode(N'▒');
    SELECT unicode(N'░');
    
    SELECT nchar(9617);
    SELECT nchar(9618);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have a working solution:

```
WITH
(
    CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

When I use the `Codepage = 'ACP'`, the txt-String comes 1:1 into my SQL-Table.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue:

```
,ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([ARTTXT], nchar(9617), '°'), nchar(9618), '±'), nchar(9600), 'ß'), '') AS [ARTTXT]
```

the problem is, that the mentioned chars - if converted to ascii - all give the same result. However, using unicode instead results in the correct characters. Here the example:

```
SELECT ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(N'30 x 1,5 mm, O-Ring, EPDM, 70░▒5░ Shore A, schwarz, Tol. nach ISO 3601', nchar(9617), '°'), nchar(9618), '±'), nchar(9600), 'ß'), '') AS [ARTTXT]
```